# Casting an interface to a dictionary

Tags: typescript, casting

I have a function `logNumbers` that accepts a dictionary where all keys are strings and all values are numbers. I want to call `logNumbers` with an object belongs to a stricter interface but still satisfies those conditions.

```
interface NumberDictionary {
  [key: string]: number;
}

interface StatisticsResult {
  mean: number;
  mode: number;
  median: number;
}

function logNumbers(numDict: NumberDictionary) { ... }

const results: StatisticsResult = {
  mean: 1,
  mode: 2,
  median: 2,
};

// 
// Error:
//   Argument of type 'StatisticsResult' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NumberDictionary'.
//   Index signature is missing in type 'StatisticsResult'.
//
logNumbers(results);
```

I would like for `StatisticsResult` to remain the same and to somehow modify the signature for `logNumbers`. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps I could signal to typescript that no new keys will be added to `numDict` within `logNumbers`?

[Reproduction in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20NumberDictionary%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20StatisticsResult%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20mean%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20mode%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20median%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20logNumbers(num%3A%20NumberDictionary)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Log%20the%20numbers%20as%20a%20table%20or%20something%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20results%3A%20StatisticsResult%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20mean%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20mode%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20median%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Error%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20Argument%20of%20type%20'StatisticsResult'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'NumberDictionary'.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20Index%20signature%20is%20missing%20in%20type%20'StatisticsResult'.%0D%0AlogNumbers(results)%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to restrict the function to an object with just number properties, you can use a generic type parameter constrained to be a record with only numbers.

```
  interface StatisticsResult {
    mean: number;
    mode: number;
    median: number;
  }

  function logNumbers<T extends Record<keyof T, number>>(num: T) {
    // Log the numbers as a table or something
  }

  const results: StatisticsResult = {
    mean: 1,
    mode: 2,
    median: 2,
  };

  //ok
  logNumbers(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is:

```
interface StatisticsResult extends NumberDictionary {
  mean: number;
  mode: number;
  median: number;
}
```

and now `StatisticsResult` will use the index signature you defined. TypeScript doesn't care about you adding new keys, it only cares that you're assigning a type with an index signature to a type without one.

You could also cast `results`, though this is much more hacky since you need to cast to `unknown` first (if you don't, ts will complain that your types don't have any overlap because of the index signagure disparity) and kind of defeats the purpose:

```
logNumbers((results as unknown) as NumberDictionary);
```

And lastly, though you said you'd rather not alter `StatisticalResult`, you could define the index signature there as well (which I understand also defeats the purpose of having your `NumberDictionary` type anyway:

```
interface StatisticsResult{
  [key: string]: number;
  mean: number;
  mode: number;
  median: number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I initially tried, but I didn't like that I could add properties to `result`. I wanted to keep it strictly limited to mean, mode, median. The use of `Record` in the other answer was what I was missing!